# Alibaba Cloud third party firewall scenario can you guide

Tags: cloud, alibaba-cloud

What is the scenario in which a client wants to use Fortinet Firewalls or Palo Alto Network Firewall in Alibaba Cloud in their cloud implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a third-party firewall could enhance your security on the cloud, as it can provide multiple layers of protection and more controls.
Both firewalls have native integration with Alibaba Cloud, so it can further improve your VPC and security groups with application/host-level segmentation and policies.
If you're already using them, you're already familiar with it, and it makes it easier to integrate with other products of the same ecosystem, such as FortiGate + FortiSandbox + FortiClient EMS.
Compliance requirement, such as PCI DSS.
You can bring your own license (BYOL) to use on Alibaba Cloud.
Both have their own features. You can read more about Palo Alto and FortiGate features. Here are some notable features:
IPsec VPN
Threat prevention (IPS)
Application and traffic control
Antivirus/Malware detection
Vulnerability management
High Avaliability (HA)